# Rails 4 link_to shows blank page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a simple link_to tag in a footer layout that says

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
```

This link redirects to the proper page, but the output is shown blank until I refresh the page. Once I refresh, it shows the proper output. Is there a problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

instead on the root path write the

```
<%= link_to "Home", 'home' %>
```

and in the pages_controller.rb

```
@title = "home"
```

this will redirected to your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Just clear up the browser data and restart the server. You may also need to remove the public/index.html.